# How could I adjust color of an image with python-opencv?

Tags: python, colors, computer-vision, opencv3.0

What I would like to do is to adjust the images like adjust the color balance of a color TV. Suppose the ratio is between (0, 1), where 0 means to adjust the image to black and white while 1 means to use the color of the original image. How could I do that with python-opencv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2


def color_balance(image, balance):
    image2 = np.zeros(image.shape)
    image2[:,:,0] = ((1 + 2*balance)*image[:,:,0] + (1 - balance)*image[:,:,1] + (1 - balance)*image[:,:,2])/3
    image2[:,:,1] = ((1 + 2*balance)*image[:,:,1] + (1 - balance)*image[:,:,0] + (1 - balance)*image[:,:,2])/3
    image2[:,:,2] = ((1 + 2*balance)*image[:,:,2] + (1 - balance)*image[:,:,0] + (1 - balance)*image[:,:,1])/3
    image2 = image2/255
    return image2


image = cv2.imread('./test.jpeg')
image = np.array(image).astype(int)
cv2.imshow("image", color_balance(image, 1))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow("image", color_balance(image, 0.5))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow("image", color_balance(image, 0))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

in the `color_balance` function, if `balance = 1` the value of each pixel will remain unchanged and if `balance = 0` the value of each pixel will be the average of all 3 channels.

Comment: Why do you divide image2 by 255?

Comment: that's just because if numbers are float python assumes the pixels are in range `[0 , 1]` so you can either cast them to integers or divide them by 255.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to enhance the color. This approach can decay the color which works well, how could I enhance it ?

Comment: just use a `balance` with value more than 1 in the same function.